# How to pattern match an element in a list in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, pattern-matching

In prolog how can you pattern match an element in a list?
For example, if the list was like

```
[1/2,1/3,2/5,3/6]
```

then you can do something like

```
one([..,1/A,..]) :- A=2.
one([..,1/A,..]) :- A=3.
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Select a certain element from the list, or match a list containing a particular element?

Comment: select an element from a list, by matching part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting elements of a list can be done in several ways, depends what you want to do with it. For example, use `select/3`:

```
?- select(1/A, [1/2,1/3,2/5,3/6], Rest).
A = 2,
Rest = [1/3, 2/5, 3/6] ;
A = 3,
Rest = [1/2, 2/5, 3/6] ;
false.
```

Or using `member/2`:

```
?- member(1/A, [1/2,1/3,2/5,3/6]).
A = 2 ;
A = 3 ;
false.
```

You can combine `select` and `member` with predicates that collect all results of backtracking, like `bagof` or `findall`, or `forall` (if you need the side effects)

Or if you feel inclined, you can actually enumerate all elements, matching only the ones you need:

```
foo([1/A|Xs]) :- !, write(A), nl, foo(Xs).
foo([_X|Xs]) :- foo(Xs).
foo([]).

?- foo([1/2,1/3,2/5,3/6]).
2
3
true.
```

Although I have the feeling this last one is not very good Prolog, as it uses a cut and the predicate has a side effect. The point was to show how you can use matching and iterate through the elements of a list.